# How to trigger pytelegrambotapi's poll_answer_handler when user doesn't respond?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

The poll has a timer of 15 seconds, if the user responds on time, the next poll is sent to them. How can I make it so that when a user doesn't respond, the next poll is sent to them when they close it?
There is a poll_answer_handler in pytelegrambotapi, but it only triggers when the user responds

`bot.send_poll(message.from_user.id, question="Question:", options=["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4"], is_anonymous=False, open_period=15)`

ChatGPT failed

Comment: "ChatGPT failed" is unhelpful for the purpose for fixing the problem...